# wrap code in a function. noob here

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I'm trying to wrap this code:

```
if($(window).width() > 980) {
   $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        //add black background
        $(".x-navbar").addClass("active");
        $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li  a").addClass("small-bar");
      } 
      else {
        //remove background
        $(".x-navbar").removeClass("active");
        $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li a").removeClass("small-bar");
      }
   });
}
```

in a function, so that I can disable it under 980px width.

The thing I'm trying to achive is something like this:

create a function as here under:

```
navBar = function () {
     // the whole code goes here.
}
```

and then "disable" it in the mobile under 980px width like this:

```
if($(window).width() < 980) {
    // DON'T run the funcion called "navBar". 
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if the window gets resized to a width under 980px the code above will not listen to the resize and it will run anyway.

Comment: i can't try that because if i wrap the whole code into navBar nothing happens now...

Comment: see my answer I think it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I mentioned in comment

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
     if($(window).width() > 980) {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        //add black background
        $(".x-navbar").addClass("active");
        $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li  a").addClass("small-bar");
      } 
      else {
        //remove background
        $(".x-navbar").removeClass("active");
        $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li a").removeClass("small-bar");
      }
     }else{
         // if window width < 980
         //remove background
        $(".x-navbar").removeClass("active");
        $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li a").removeClass("small-bar");
     }
   });
```

Comment: looks good! but how do i say if window width is < 980 don't run the addClass code?

Comment: @PaoloMangia answer updated .. you should remove class after resize

Answer (score 0):

You can register a function that will be called when window.resize method is triggered.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    //Here you can check the width
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because once you instantiate a listener, it will not be removed until you explicitly remove it. Check out jQuery's [off function](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove a listener. You can then switch between `off()` and `on()` depending on the window size.