# How to make a fixed header change colour on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I say header I mean a `<h1>`. But I have a fixed header on the left side of my page and I am using a parallax so that as I scroll down the background div changes.

I want the colour of h1 to change as I scroll down, exactly like [this website](http://www.nightshiftpost.com/) does. (check the nightshift header on the top left!).

I have tried using Jquery like this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2600) {
    $(".leftHeaders a").css("color", "black");
```

But you dont get the cool transition of colour as you scroll down.

Comment: If you inspect the page you linked to you can see how it's being done; the 'nightshift' wording is two separate SVG - one black and one white. These are then being clipped in line with the boundary between slides to give the transition effect. This is *far* more complicated than just changing the CSS properties of an element

Comment: You can see question already asked before:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757193/change-background-of-fixed-header-when-scrolling-past-elements]

Answer (score 1):

You should put your code inside $(window).scroll() like this

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 2600) {
    $(".leftHeaders a").css("color", "black");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use event listener, and trying to change color only once.

You can try something like this:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2600) {
      $(".leftHeaders a").css("color", "black");
    }
      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 2600) {
    //add black background
    $(".leftHeaders a").css("color", "black");
  } 
  else {
    //remove background
  }
});
```

you can refer to this old question i posted time ago: 
[wrap code in a function. noob here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577783/wrap-code-in-a-function-noob-here/33577849#33577849) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think You want something like this-

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                var top = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (top > 2600) {
                   $(".leftHeaders a").css("color", "black");

                } 
               else {
                   $(".leftHeaders a").css("color", "red");

                }

 })
```